# Error messages everytime GUI text editor is opened from terminal

Tags: gnome, gui, editors, error-handling, dconf

Whenever I open Gnome Text Editor from the terminal using the command `gnome-text-editor ./example.txt`, I get the following error messages:

```
(gnome-text-editor:9560): dconf-WARNING **: 00:00:58.433: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(gnome-text-editor:9560): dconf-WARNING **: 00:00:58.444: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)

(gnome-text-editor:9560): dconf-WARNING **: 00:00:59.141: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(gnome-text-editor:9560): dconf-WARNING **: 00:00:59.142: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(gnome-text-editor:9560): dconf-WARNING **: 00:00:59.142: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
```

Despite the error messages using the editor works fine. It even saves properly. I get another message when closing the GUI.

```
(gnome-text-editor:9560): dconf-WARNING **: 00:01:18.853: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
```

Should I be concerned about these messages? Is gnome-text-editor damaged?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal.

GUI apps tend to spew lots of warning messages to STDERR, under the assumption that they've been started from a menu or icon and all such output will be redirected to `~/.xsession-errors`.

You can always redirect stderr (and optionally stdout too) to /dev/null, e.g. in `bash`:

```
 gnome-text-editor ./example.txt &> /dev/null
```

or append to ~/.xsession-errors:

```
 gnome-text-editor ./example.txt &>> ~/.xsession-errors
```